# How do I export the results into an Excel spreadsheet and highlight them in green once the files have been deleted from a csv list in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a powershell script that removes files from a csv list. However, I'm not sure how to export the results once the files have been deleted from the list and mark them in green in a spreadsheet in Excel. How would I approach this? Below is my powershell script:

```
$files = Get-Content "C:\test\remove.csv"
foreach ($file in $files) {
Remove-Item -Path $file -force
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that but nothing happens.

Comment: By "the results", do you mean which files where removed? Do you care why the remove failed? Reg how to approach: [check out this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/01/10/powershell-and-excel-fast-safe-and-reliable/). It covers creating a custom CSV that Excel is happy with, and a bit on creating the Com Object. For more help, please give it a go and post if you have specific problems.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to export the files that were removed from remove.csv. So how would I incorporate it this in powershell by using my script: $files = Get-Content "C:\test\remove.csv"
foreach ($file in $files) {
Remove-Item -Path $file -force
}